# Add LDFLAGS in qt .pro field

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

How to add LDFLAGS in qt .pro field?

consider Library folder and shared library(.so) is in a dir_path folder.

For example, adding this line is not solving the issue
**LIBS+= -Ldir_path -llibrary_name**

Any suggestions?

Comment: In my case, adding `LIBS += -Ldir_path -llibrary_name` was the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 7):

qmake has the `QMAKE_LFLAGS` variable for it.

You can read about qmake variables [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html).

Comment: QMAKE_LFLAGS add LFLAGS to Makefile. I need LDFLAGS in Makefile. What now?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use "TEMPLATE = app" to get the correct behavior. Using the "lib" template would ignore the LIBS variable.

Answer (score 0):

use QMAKE_LDFLAGS for your requirement.